# CSS Grid break Angular

Tags: css, angular, gridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to implement CSS grid template which should behaves as follows:

1. with equal width of columns
2. **1st and 3rd lines** - 2 columns

   **2nd line** - 3 columns

[image]

```
Order = [{      
    details:[
      {
        key: '1',
        label: 'Name',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        key: '2',
        label: 'Age',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        key: '3',
        label: 'Valid From'
      },
      {
        key: '4',
        label: 'Valid To'
      },
      {
        key: '5',
        label: 'Product'
      },
      {
        key: '6',
        label: 'State'
      },
      {
        key: '7',
        label: 'Country'
      }}]
```

As per the above Json I have create the css grid

```
    <div class="order-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-header vds-type-copy-strong"   *ngFor="let col of salesOrder1[0].details">
                <div>{{col.label}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   .order-container {
    .grid-item {
        padding: 5px;
        max-height: 402px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 4px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        .grid-header {
            text-align: center;
            div{
                padding: 8px 8px;
                margin-bottom: 4px;
                min-height: 37px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to break the  content after **Age** and then after **product**?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is this way. I am not sure how toapply this in angular but just to give you some idea. maybe you can create a blank box see if that will will help you.. Let me know.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: gray; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;}

.box {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 80px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  }

.hiddenbox {
  background-color: transparent;
  border:0px solid transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="hiddenbox box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The value is coming as JSON. So how will create hidden box?